# The example of promises and then

Tags: javascript

Recently i heard 'promises' and tried to learn how it works and say...
it's not working well.

```js
    function example(){
      return new Promise(function(){
        var i=0;
        while(i<5000){console.log(i);i++;}
      })
    }
            
    example()
    .then(
      function(){
        console.log('done')
      },
      function(){
        console.log('error')
      });
```

it writes 1-4999 but never writes 'done' or 'error'.. how can I make it write 'then' clause?

Your kind reply would be appreciated.

Comment: `Promise(function(resolve, reject){` instead of `Promise(function(){` and in the body of the promise function put a `resolve();` after the loop (or somewhere), basically.

Comment: Aren't these two anonymous functions just defined, and never actually executed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank you so much, got the problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

---

Promises gets two arguments: ***resolve & reject*** that will be the functions to  be executed as the defined at the ***.then() & .catch()***. So to be able get print the 'done' or 'error' You should do something like this:

```
function example(condition){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var i=0;
    while(i<5000){console.log(i);i++;}
    if(condition){
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  })
}
example(true).then(function(){console.log('done')},function(){console.log('error')});//Prints 'done'

example(false).then(function(){console.log('done')},function(){console.log('error')});//Prints 'error'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function example() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 5000) {
      console.log(i);
      i++;
    }
    resolve(i);
  })
}

example()
  .then(
    function() {
      console.log('done')
    },
    function() {
      console.log('error')
    });
```

You need resolve, reject callbacks. In your code your Promise always stays in pending state.

Comment: Yes, Now I realized that's what I missed on it.
Thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...  https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/

Ex.:

```
function example() {

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        try{

          var i = 0;

          while(i < 5000){

            console.log('proccess',i);

            i++;

          }

          resolve(i);// an if, to resolve or reject...

        } catch(error) {

          reject(error);

        }

      });

    }

    console.log('will call the promise');

    example().then(function(success){

      console.log('caller promise result', success);

    }).catch(function(error){

      console.log('if some problem, catch',error.toString());

    });

    console.log('Here, will be before or after the promise resolves');
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.. Now I think I  got it right :)